# current_user in devise displays only two fields authentication token and email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

> @user = current_user

when using render json:@user, it displays

```
{"user":{"authentication_token":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","email":"sample@example.com"}}
```

but i want

```
{"user":{"authentication_token":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","email":"sample@example.com","country":"india"}}
```

How can i do this?

Comment: What are the fields you are expecting?

Comment: Take for example country as i have mentioned in the question.

Comment: Does country is database column or method in user model?

Comment: database column in user model

Comment: Try render json:@user.to_json

Comment: And the result is same as before

Comment: Add attr_accessible :country to your user model.Its my final solution.